# OpenCV in ROS indigo

Tags: ros, opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ros users:

I have a script where I use OpenCV functions and ROS functions.
But I have a problem when I run this script.
Mi question is:  What version of OpenCV have I to install to work with Ros Indigo?

Thanks a lot!!!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220544/opencv-in-ros-indigo/) by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2015-11-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2015-11-07**:
What problems are those? And just to be sure: you use python, right?

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2016-03-11**:
And further: How did you install ROS and OpenCV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`cv_bridge` works with opencv2 (http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages)

---

Originally posted by [alee](https://answers.ros.org/users/26002/alee/) with karma: 194 on 2016-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0